# opened file in the memory space

Tags: c++, c, linux

[linux 3.2] I am wondering if it is possible to find out the memory location of a file opened in a program.
Suppose I have the code below in a.cpp which compiles to a.out:

```
FILE *f = fopen("myfile", "r");
```

Will the content be mapped into the memory space of a.out? If so, how could I find it(the pages? the range?) out?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you want to directly access the content of the file, use `mmap`. `fopen` is at the wrong level of abstraction ... even if some implementation of stdio used `mmap` internally, it's not part of the API.

Comment: Also, "the memory space of a.out" is a bit confused. a.out is an executable file on disk -- a static object; it doesn't have a memory space. When you execute a.out -- which you can do multiple times simultaneously -- your create a *process*; processes have address spaces.

Comment: @JimBalter Trying to do some analysis on an application with its source code. If the file contents were mapped, I can tell if the application is reading the certain file by watching binary instructions which access the certain memory location. Otherwise I think I need to find out the routines in the source code that may access the THAT file content by reading the source code.

Comment: @JimBalter I agree with the use of "process". Thanks.

Comment: it sounds like you want http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure to which the FILE* points holds some information about the state of the file. The contents are not mapped into program's memory space.

If you want to map file contents into the memory space you have to use mmap() function. This will give you a pointer to a memory region in the process's logical memory space. This memory region will hold the contents of the file.

Comment: "Then you will just see a pointer ..." .. that's a bit misleading. The pointer points to file data that has been paged into the process's address space.

Comment: Yup, I should clarify that.

Comment: To be precise, in glibc there is "m" open mode: _The file is opened and accessed using mmap. This is only supported with files opened for reading._ http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-Streams.html

Comment: @JimBalter: I don't think that you can say "file data that has been **paged** into the process". That's true for simple disk files, but the Linux file abstraction covers many other things such as `/dev/tty`, and that's something which you definitely cannot page in.

Comment: @MSalters Please read more carefully. Notably, the text I quoted does not appear in the answer -- it's from an earlier version. The context is mmap ... you can't mmap /dev/tty

Comment: @JimBalter: Right, current version is indeed clearer. `mmap` is indeed a form of paging.

Comment: In both versions of the answer, "pointer" refers to a value provided by `mmap`; the "file abstraction" and /dev/tty were never relevant.